# JSDoc define function only in docs

Tags: jsdoc

I'm using a IDE i want autocomplete some function but the function are not defined in the code then I have a warning.

for example

i have the object

```
var client = getRemoteClien();

// here is the warning    
client.firstMethod(....)
```

How I can use JSDoc to add the function `firstMethod` of the variables `client`

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the IDE you are using and thus cannot be generally answered. Typically IDE do allow you to use a JSDoc-umented stub-API which you include into your project. It does however heavily depend on the IDE and the JS support/plugins available.

For IntelliJ you might want to check out this http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/11/working-with-javascript-libraries-in-phpstorm-webstorm/